# Linear momentum vs Linear kinetic energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, momentum

While a car needs the quadruple of the time to stop if its speed had doubled, why does a rocket in space needs only the double of time to accelerate to the double of its speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A car only needs double the time to stop at double the speed.  It needs quadruple the *distance*.